# add select2 to dyanamically added element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to apply select2 js to my dyanamically created element, can please anyone help me with this

```
var a_html = '<div class="card skill_card"><div class="card-body media align-items-center"><div class="media-left mr-3"><span class="js-dragula-handle material-icons" style="cursor: move;">drag_handle</span></div><div class="media-body">' + '<a href="#<%=@pathn%>"><strong><%= @pathn %></strong></a>' + '</div><div class="media-right"><a href="" class="btn btn-flush ml-12pt" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="Delete Path" data-placement="bottom" data-caret="false"><i class="material-icons icon-16pt">delete_outline</i></a></div></div></div>'

$(a_html).appendTo(".path_panel");

$('.path_list').append('<div id="<%= @pathn -%>"></div>');
<% js = escape_javascript(render(partial: 'admin/programmes/path', locals: { pathn: @pathn })) %>
$("#"+"<%= @pathn -%>").append("<%= js %>");
$("#"+"<%= @pathn -%>").find(".custom-select").select2();
```

Partial page code--- _path.html.erb

```
        <div class="form-group d-flex align-items-end mb-16pt">
        <div class="form-group col-lg-8 mb-8pt pl-0">
            <label class="form-label" for="select03">Add Examples Tech</label>
            <p class="text-left">Description.</p>
            <select id="skill_select" data-toggle="select" multiple class="form-control custom-select" data-path="<%=@pathn%>">
                <%skills_data = skills_data ? skills_data : Org.skills_and_technologies%>
                <% skills_data.each do |sk| %>
                <option title="<%= "#{sk.klass}_#{sk.id}" %>"><%= sk.name.capitalize %></option>
                <% end %>
            </select>               
        </div>
        <div class=""><%= submit_tag "Add", :name => nil, class: "btn btn-accent btn-rounded mb-8pt ml-16pt add_skill", id: @pathn %></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: If you execute that in a js template when it fails you don't receive any errors in the browser console. Are you sure there are no errors? The code looks ok..

Comment: @razvans no errors, just select2 is not applied to selectbox

Comment: try `setTimeout(function() {$("#"+"<%= @pathn -%>").find(".custom-select").select2() }, 0)`, though it wouldn't make sense because append is synchronous.

Comment: Can you please share the code where `.custom-select` is being added as I was unable to find any class with that name in the given code. If it is in another file then it might be possible that it is being added after the js has been executed.

Comment: @AbdulRehman I have added the partial where you can find 'custom-select'

Comment: How is the `_path' partial being render? is it through a js.erb?

Comment: @AbdulRehman- yes, you can see in the given code

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to mind, if the entire js template is error free, is that the browser doesn't see the `.custom-select` right after that `append`.

AFAIK `append` is synchronous and the select should be applied. Please try this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $("#"+"<%= @pathn -%>").find(".custom-select").select2() 
}, 0)
```